# Sublime Text 2: Make the window wider when viewing the side bar

Tags: sublimetext2

When you view/invoke the side bar in Sublime Text 2, the width of the window stays constant—the *side bar* appears on the left, *code* in the middle and the *mini-map* on the right. This usually “squishes” the code view…

Is there a way to keep the *code* and *mini-map* locked to a specific width and force the window to grow **wider** when you invoke the side bar view? (Similar to how the project drawer works in TextMate.)

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, there is currently no way to do this.

Comment: Darn. Oh well, I know I am splitting hairs, but it would be cool to be able to do that. :)

Comment: You can suggest it on [Sublime Text 2's UserEcho forum](http://sublimetext.userecho.com/).

Comment: There already is an UserEcho entry for this: [Add a window width option ... / General forum / Sublime Text](http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/130255-add-a-window-width-option-for-use-when-toggling-sidebar/)

Comment: While this would be nice, I don't see how you would deal with it if your window is already maximized.